# How to ignore words that have only 1/2 letters in a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 2 csv files, dictionary.csv and news.csv, where i match the words contained in dictionary.csv in the news.csv. But, apparently i kept on getting matches even when i shouldn't. I'm not sure if its because my code matches for every letter or term, can someone help?

Below are my codes:

```
news=pd.read_csv("news.csv")
capitalizednews=news['STORY'].str.title() #to capitalize each first letter in news csv

dictionary=pd.read_csv("dictionary.csv")

capitalizeddict=dictionary['Lists'].str.title().str.replace(',','').str.replace('(','').str.replace(')','').str.replace('-','').str.replace('\d','')#to capitalize each first letter in dictionary and remove 

splitterm = capitalizeddict.str.split('\s+',expand=True).stack().unique().tolist()

pattern='|'.join(splitterm) #to join all of the terms in dictionary.csv


news["contain term"] =np.where(capitalizednews.str.contains(pattern,regex=True,case=False),1,0)
```

I kept on getting 1 for all of my 'contain term' column.

Although, i keep getting this feeling that because some of my terms after split, became a 1/2 letter word(like P, Aa), so i would like to ignore these terms

Comment: It seems `capitalizednews` is merely the row `'STORY'` with title case, not the whole document

Comment: The code reading the lists *should* be irrelevant

Comment: Don't just do `'|'.join`, you should add word bounds as well, so you match whole words, not partial matches. Do `pattern = r'\b' + r'\b|\b'.join(splitterm) + r'\b'` so that each word from splitterm has beginning and ending word bound.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring any possible problems with the code reading, this is a general function for doing what you lined out assuming words are any strings in the title with any iterable (note that it returns a list):

```
def weed_out_short_words(wordlist):
    wordlist2 = []
    for word in wordlist:
        if word.length <= 2:
            pass
        else:
            wordlist2.append(word)
```

This does **not** remove entries in a table where a specific column has words with two letters or less. It also doesn't deal with strings composed of multiple words, like "Hello world".

Furthermore, your code seems to jumble up what any given thing represents. Since I don't actually know what the colums of your `.csv` are, I can't help any further ATM.

Answer (score 0):

Removing only one- and two-letter words will still cause problems. "cat" will be still recognised in "catastrophe". It's a 3-letter word. There's much more examples when this could fail.

That's why you need to check whole words, not only substrings.

Since you're using regex with "or" (`|`), you can also use regex word borders `r'\b'`:

```
pattern = r'\b' + r'\b|\b'.join(splitterm) + r'\b'
```

This thing will use whole `r'\b|\b'` as a separator, and add `r'\b` to the beginning of first word and the end of the last word.

Using raw strings (`r'...'`) here because it's regex and we're using regex special character `\b`, not using an escaping sequence.